# Cannot insert data into an sqlite3 database using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I can successfully use Python to create a database and run the execute() method to create 2 new tables and specify the column names. However, I cannot insert data into the database. This is the code that I am trying to use to insert the data into the database:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3

companies = ('GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT')

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = db.cursor()

for company in companies:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO companies VALUES (?)', (company,))
```

Here is the code that I use to successfully create the database with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

db.execute('CREATE TABLE companies ' \
      '( '\
      'company varchar(255) '\
      ')')

db.execute('CREATE TABLE data ' \
      '( '\
      'timestamp int, '\
      'company int, '\
      'shares_held_by_all_insider int, '\
      'shares_held_by_institutional int, '\
      'float_held_by_institutional int, '\
      'num_institutions int '\
      ')')
```

Comment: It worked fine for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nope, everything seemed to run fine other than the fact that the records weren't being added to the table.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to add

```
db.commit()
```

after the inserting.

Answer (score 4):

To insert the data you don't need a cursor

just use the  db

db.execute() instead of c.execute()  and get rid of the c = db.cursor() line

Cursors aren't used to insert data, but usually to read data, or update data in place.